# SQL Server 2012 - Stopword Error

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I am doing an exercise in Microsoft 70-461 certification book (written by Itzik Ben-Gan)
 In chapter 6-Query Full text data. I run the following query to create a stopword list. 
 The system showed me an error message.

> Msg 9966, Level 16, State 106, Line 135 Cannot use full-text search in
>   master, tempdb, or model database.

Here is the query I am trying to run

```
use master;
 create fulltext stoplist SQLStopList;
 GO
 alter FULLTEXT STOPLIST SQLStopList
 ADD 'SQL' LANGUAGE 'English';
```

Please give me some advises on what caused the error and how to fix it

Is there a log I can check to see what might went wrong. You advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dear forum mediators, as a beginner to SQL server, I have learned that I can't use master database to conduct full-text search. I should use the test database instead. This question might be a good reference for the beginners who want to learn about full-text search using SQL server 2012.

Answer (score 4):

You're using master. Like the error message says, you can't do that in master. Try using the TSQL2012 database.

Comment: Hello Katherine thanks for the reply. I used the database TSQL2012 to create the SQLStopList. It worked. I didn't receive any error message.

Answer (score -1):

```
"...Cannot use full-text search in master, tempdb, or model database."
```

You just can't use the master, tempdb or model database for full-text search.